# XSS protection in .htaccess, removing a script tag from URL

Tags: .htaccess, validation, url, redirect, xss

Can anyone help me   remove `"><script>alert(7229)</script>` from the   url in .htaccess file with this condition

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
```

I can only match query string but the link below doesn't have any query string, just `"><script>alert(7229)</script>`. I need a solution which can match and   redirect it back to home page.

```
http://example.com/"><script>alert(7229)</script>
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^home/index.cgi/ \"(.+)$ home/index.cgi/?$1 [R]

should this work?

Comment: Also check that [none of these other techniques can bypass your filter](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet).